# Does 'ignore' of validation in jQuery make all validation not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

When I use 'ignore' of validate() method, submission has been proceeded regardless of the result of validation(good or bad).

It is like 'ignore' make validation of all input elements bypass. So even if one or more input elements don't satisfy conditions for validation, the form has been submitted and server will work.

Oh, in my case, 'ignore' makes submitHandler and (even!) invalidHandler not work either.

What's wrong point? Here's my sampled(not entire) code below.

```
$('#frm').validate({
                submitHandler: function() {
                    var applyMsg = "Proceed?";
                    var f = confirm(applyMsg);

                    if(f) {
                        //console.log(" confirm  : "+ f );
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        //console.log(" no confirm  : "+ f );
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    if (errors) {
                        alert(validator.errorList[0].message);
                        validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
                    }
                },
                ignore: '.ignore',
                rules: {
                    PHOTO_PLACE: {photo_place: true}
                },
                messages: {
                    PHOTO_PLACE: {required: ""},
                    ENT_DATE: {minlength: "", maxlength: ""}
                }
            });




<form id="frm" name="frm" method="post" class="app_frm">
    <input type="hidden" id="PHOTO_PLACE" name="PHOTO_PLACE" />
    <input type="text" name="ENT_DATE" minlength="8" maxlength="8" class="ignore" />
</form>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Well once you've ignored the text box, you've only got one other field - "photo place", and I'm not sure sure you've set the rules for it correctly. Looking at the documentation (https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) I'm pretty sure it should be `rules { PHOTO_PLACE: { required: true; } }`. Otherwise it's hard to see how the validator will know which of the many possible rules must resolve as true in order to validate it. Try that and see if you still have an issue. Also, if you say the submit handler isn't running at all, check your console for any errors.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your response. About submit handler, there's not any error in browser console. And I set rules as PHOTO_PLACE: {required: true; }, but it won't make it. In this case, I coded it by bypassing not to check specified inputs without 'ignore'.